# iOS location using wifi networks

Tags: ios, geolocation, location, wifi

I need to know if is possible to get user location using wifi networks in iOS.

I read about the method significant location changes, but I dont know if it is necessary that the user connects to the wireless network or simply when de device detects a new wifi network around the event is fired.

As you see I have no idea of the subject, anyone can guide me a bit?

Comment: I don't think that's your work. All you need to do is get the coordiantes which device returned to you. I think It's Apple's thing to accurate the location.

Comment: What I do is this, When the user enter some wifi networks, if the network is one of interest for the app alert the user.

Answer (score -1):

```
Used Reachability class
@property (nonatomic) Reachability *hostReachability;
@property (nonatomic) Reachability *internetReachability;
@property (nonatomic) Reachability *wifiReachability;

Call below method in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
-(void)makeConnectionOverRechability {

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reachabilityChanged:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil]; //When intenet connectivity change this method call

    NSString *remoteHostName = @"www.apple.com";
    self.hostReachability = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:remoteHostName];
    [self.hostReachability startNotifier];
    [self updateInterfaceWithReachability:self.hostReachability];

    self.internetReachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    [self.internetReachability startNotifier];
    [self updateInterfaceWithReachability:self.internetReachability];

    self.wifiReachability = [Reachability reachabilityForLocalWiFi];
    [self.wifiReachability startNotifier];
    [self updateInterfaceWithReachability:self.wifiReachability];

}

#pragma mark-
#pragma mark Internect Connectivity
-(BOOL)checkInternetConnection
{
    Reachability *reach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"www.google.com"];
    NetworkStatus internetStatus = [reach currentReachabilityStatus];
    if ((internetStatus != ReachableViaWiFi) && (internetStatus != ReachableViaWWAN))
    {
        return internetStatus;
    }
    return internetStatus;
}

- (void) reachabilityChanged:(NSNotification *)note
{
    Reachability* curReach = [note object];
    NSParameterAssert([curReach isKindOfClass:[Reachability class]]);
    [self updateInterfaceWithReachability:curReach];
}

- (void)updateInterfaceWithReachability:(Reachability *)reachability
{
    if (reachability == self.hostReachability)
    {

    }
    if (reachability == self.internetReachability)
    {
        [self configureTextField:reachability];
    }

    if (reachability == self.wifiReachability)
    {
        [self configureTextField:reachability];
    }
}

- (void)configureTextField:(Reachability *)reachability
{
    NetworkStatus netStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];

//check here only wifi connection

    switch (netStatus)
    {
        case NotReachable:  {
            NSLog(@"not Connected+++++++++++");

            break;
        }
        case ReachableViaWWAN:  {
            NSLog(@"Connected");
                      break;
        }
        case ReachableViaWiFi: {
            NSLog(@"Connected");

            }
            break;
        }
}
```

Comment: First , thanks for your help.I dont understand all the code you've shared. Which it is supposed to detect a new wireless network . It would require the user to log into the network? It works with the app in background?

Comment: else if (status == ReachableViaWWAN) 
{
    //2G, 3G,4G
} ...here you can detect network. This work if in background mode as well whenever you need check connection if ([kAppDelegateObject checkInternetConnection]) { }

Comment: (status == ReachableViaWWAN) 
{
    //3G ,2G

Comment: there should be some comment to explain what is done, instead of just throwing code.